# Binding compile command to a key for c++ code

Tags: c++, compilation

Is it possible to bind the `compile` and run commands for a c++ code to a single key (for example F5). What i do at the moment is to run `M-x compile` and then as compile command `g++ project.cpp` and then i run `./a.out` in a shell. Does anyone has a solution for doing these with less typing for c++?

Answer (score 5):

You need to do two things: 1. Bind `compile` to a key (like `f5`) 2. Change the command that `compile` runs.

To do the first add `(define-key c++-mode-map [f5] #'compile)` to your `.emacs`.  This sets the key only in `c++-mode`; you can make it a global binding if you want by using `global-map` instead.

For the second, the `compile` function just runs whatever is stored in the variable `compile-command`.  Changing this globally would be a pain as you probably want different commands for different projects.  File local variables to the rescue.  Open the file and run `M-x add-file-local-variable`.  Chose `compile-command` as the variable and `"g++ project.cpp && ./a.out"` as the value (don't forget the quotes).  This will add a block

```
// Local Variables:
// compile-command: "g++ test.cpp && ./a.out"
// End:
```

to the bottom of your file.  You can easily add this block yourself if you like.

If your project has multiple files, use `add-dir-local-variable` instead.  Directory local variables are used by all files in that directory.

Comment: After adding the line to my init.el and reopening emacs i get this error: `Symbol's value as variable is void: c++-mode-map`.

Comment: That just means `c++-mode` isn't loaded yet.  Try wrapping it with  `with-eval-after-load`:  `(with-eval-after-load "cc-mode" (define-key c++-mode-map [f5] #'compile))`.  That way it won't run until after `cc-mode` loads and `c++-mode-map` exists.

Comment: Trying to do this and I cannot add a file local variable. Following your instructions, I get the error message: `read-file-local-variable-value: Trailing garbage following expression`. I am definitely using `add-file-local-variable`(not _read_). Even just pasting in the compile-command at the end of the file doesn't work. I still get prompted to enter a compile-command every time (with the usual `make -k` as default).

Comment: @n1k31t4 I don't recognize that error, but it still works on my machine.  Try asking adding more details and asking as a new question.

Comment: @erikstokes - it was  my mistake - using the function interactively, I did not place it within quotes.

Answer (score -1):

I wonder why you use Emacs, if you don't write Elisp at all. For example, http://www.nathan1hughes.co.uk/programming/why-i-persisted-to-learn-emacs/ suits your question well, on the bottom of the blog:

```
 ;; Run C programs directly from within emacs
(defun execute-c-program ()
  (interactive)
  (defvar foo)
  (setq foo (concat "gcc " (buffer-name) " && ./a.out" ))
  (shell-command foo))
```

Comment: Not sure what the patronizing is for.